# How to force WebDialog in Facebook Android SDK use facebook.com and not m.facebook.com?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, dialog, request

I'm building an Android app with the Facebook SDK (3.0.1). On sending a friend request using the WebDialog, Facebook returns "Sorry, something went wrong." I reported this to Facebook bugs and someone said that it's a problem when sending the request using m.facebook.com/dialogs. So I'm trying to force the WebDialog to use facebook.com/dialogs. Any tips on what to modify in the SDK code?

I asked about the case for this issue a while back over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883774/android-sdk-friend-request-returns-sorry-something-went-wrong) if you want to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending a friend request on mobile is not supported. So unfortunately you won't be able to add this functionality.

Comment: I successfully did this before with the same code. It stopped working in February.